# How to Implement Cloudinary Upload Widget in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, cloudinary

I'm trying to use the Cloudinary Upload Widget in my React App but i have a problem.
When running the project, the Upload Widget appears immediately, but when closed and opened again, the app crashes and displays the following message:

> widget.open() is not a function

**Note:**
The upload works correctly

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  showWidget = (widget) => {
    widget.open();
  }

  checkUploadResult = (resultEvent) => {
    if(resultEvent.event === 'success'){
      console.log(resultEvent)
    }
  }
  render() {
      let widget = window.cloudinary.openUploadWidget({
      cloudName: "*********",
      uploadPreset: "tryingfirsttime"},
      (error, result) => {this.checkUploadResult(result)});

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.showWidget}> Upload file</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://widget.cloudinary.com/v2.0/global/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZ1wj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtmWW.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's understand the issue. The Cloudinary upload widget is defined in the render function of the component and when that component is rendered, it will open the upload widget since it's defined with the functionality of `openUploadWidget`. Secondly, the widget is defined only in the scope of the render function and not accessible outside of it, hence the error `widget.open() is not a function`.

To remedy these issues, I would first start by defining the widget either as a local variable or part of the state. This is done by including the constructor as part of your component:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props)

   // Defined in state
   this.state = { . . . }

   // Defined as local variable
   this.widget = myLocalVariable
}
```

The next thing to do is when creating an instance of the Cloudinary upload widget, to use `createUploadWidget` and not `openUploadWidget`, to allow control of when to open the widget.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   // Defined in state
   this.state = {
      widget: cloudinary.createUploadWidget({
         cloudName: 'my_cloud_name', 
         uploadPreset: 'my_preset'}, 
         (error, result) => { 
            if (!error && result && result.event === "success") { 
               console.log('Done! Here is the image info: ', result.info); 
            }
         }
      })
    }
    // Defined as local variable
    this.widget = cloudinary.createUploadWidget({
       cloudName: 'my_cloud_name', 
       uploadPreset: 'my_preset'}, (error, result) => { 
         if (!error && result && result.event === "success") { 
           console.log('Done! Here is the image info: ', result.info); 
         }
       }
    })
 }
```

Lastly, the showWidget click event does not need the widget passed as an argument (since it's defined locally in the component) and can be referred too with the `this` keyword. Note that you'll need to include the keyword this to refer to the current component.

```
showWidget = () => {
  this.widget.open();
}
```

I have included a JSFiddle showing the end result:
https://jsfiddle.net/danielmendoza/fve1kL53/

Answer (score 0):

I will add that you might need to rewrite the showWidget function to prevent the event default if you're trying to set the state with the URL result. Otherwise, you'll get an error that you cannot use setState() in an unmounted component.

```
showWidget = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.widget.open();
}
```